# Ajustar altura JTable dependiendo de las filas

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Tengo un `JTable` llamado "tabla" el cual carga los días de conexión del administrador en la aplicación. Los guarda en una tabla llamada en `MySQL`. **¿Por qué no se ajusta el contenido (filas) al tamaño de altura del JTable?** ¿Hay algún método? Si hay **>=5 filas** muestra un `jScrollPane` pero ¿se podría controlar <5 filas para ajustar el tamaño del `JTable` (así eliminar el espacio gris del `Jtable`?

**Código:**

```
     try {
            resizer();
            DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
            tabla.setModel(modelo);

            TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(modelo);
            tabla.setRowSorter(sorter);

            //Realizamos la consulta.
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Connection con = Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("clientesSL");

            String sql = "SELECT c.fecha FROM conexiones AS c, administradores AS a \n"
                    + "WHERE a.administrador= '" +administrador+ "' AND a.id_administrador = c.id_administrador;";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rsMd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
            int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

            modelo.addColumn("FECHAS CONEXIONES");
            tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);

            DefaultTableCellRenderer tcr = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
            tcr.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(tcr);

            //Recorrer el array e imprimir los datos en las celdas.
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
                for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) {
                    filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                }
                modelo.addRow(filas);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
```

**Imagen:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a pintar, de nuevo, la tabla pero no resulta efectivo:

```
private void resizer() {
    revalidate();
    int w = jscrollpane.getPreferredSize().width; //width scroll pane
    int h1 = jscrollpane.getViewport().getViewSize().height; //height viewport
    int h2 = tabla.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize().height; //table height

    if (h1 < h2) {
        jscrollpane.setSize(new Dimension(w, h1+30));
    } else {
        jscrollpane.setSize(tabla.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize());
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene el código del TableModel. ¿Y el JTable dónde está? Ahí se vería que tú le das dimensiones cuando estás pintando el Panel. Para actualizarlo, habría que recalcular la altura de acuerdo al contenido y usar `repaint()`

Comment: @Alfabravo El `JTable` es un Swing control. `import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;`

Comment: No. Una cosa es cómo modelas los datos que vas a mostrar (el TableModel) y otra, el elemento de la GUI (la JTable). Tienes `tabla.setModel(modelo);`, entonces, cómo defines a `tabla` y qué atributos le fijas?

Comment: @Alfabravo He actualizado la pregunta.

Comment: Vale, eso bonito que haces en GUI tiene código detrás. Tienes minSize, PreferredSize y tal. Tendrías que actualizar, CON CÓDIGO, el preferredSize y hacer repaint, a partir de un listener que valide cuándo se cargan datos.

Comment: @Alfabravo Estoy implementando el código para pintar de nuevo el `JTable` pero no me funciona. He realizado una función llamada resizer(); la acabo de añadir en la pregunta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133569/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-alfabravo).

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo mas simple que puedes hacer es que a medida que vas agregando filas a la tabla también vas a agrandando la altura del *scroll pane*.

Lo siguiente me funciona perfectamente al momento de recorrer el `ResultSet`:

```
  while (rs.next()) {
      Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
      for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) {
          filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
      }
      modelo.addRow(filas);

      if(modelo.getRowCount()<6) {
        jscrollpane.setSize(jscrollpane.getSize().width,
                            jscrollpane.getSize().height+tabla.getRowHeight());
      }
  }
```

El condicional garantiza que solo al tener entre 1 a 5 registros la tabla va aumentar la altura conforme a su *row height*, de modo contrario con mas de 5 filas se activara la barra del `JScrollPane`.

De paso, con lo anterior, no necesitas mas al método `resizer()`

Brevemente a manera de inciso, en mis pruebas usé arbitrariamente una instrucción `jscrollpane.setBounds(10,10,300,27);` para ubicar y dimensionar el componente en el *frame*, con lo cual solo se verá el *header* de la tabla si no hay filas, ¿por que?, porque son aproximadamente 27 pixeles de altura los que tiene la barra de títulos de esa tabla (*podría variar si se cambia el tamaño de la fuente*).

Comment: Buenos días, acabo de implementar tu código de la condicional "modelo.getRowCount()" en mi código: ejecuta correctamente pero al resultado esperado no se consigue. Me sigue sucediendo el mismo error.